# Zabbix trigger to detect no data

Tags: zabbix

I need trigger able to detect that polled Zabbix agent items does not returns data.
For zabbix trapper items this functionality is covered by nodata() function (Heartbeat lost detection in Zabbix documentation) but I need similar functionality supported for Zabbix agent items.

For example, a have defined Zabbix agent UserParameter:
`UserParameter=custom.mssqlping,/usr/local/scripts/mssqlping.sh`.

The script mssqlping.sh returns 0/1. I need to cover situation when mssqlping.sh script is broken and returns empy string, which is not stored in zabbix because it is not number.

How to detect that periodically polled item data are no longer coming?

Comment: After years of Zabbix monitoring implementation I have reached ZEN level, and NOW, the problem is easily sovable using Item preprocessing, that reacts on non-number string by replacing it by my own number error value!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not that it's not stored that creates the problem but the fact that it is not being considered as a valid item anymore so you can't trigger anything out of it. There is a plenty of related bug reports related to it. AFAIk your options:

1. Adjust the script to return a numeric value in case of errors
2. Use [2.2's "internal events"](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/events/sources) to detect the "becomes unsupported" event
3. Make and external script that will query the database directly and will notify you on its own or triggering a condition through zabbix's trappers

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will check internal evenst. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Just additional info after years - now the preprocessing rule can check for invalid incoming number and replace it by my own error number (e.g. 2)
This prevents Item become unsupported

Answer (score 1):

Or the option here is to trigger based on [nodata()](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/triggers/functions)

from: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/41652-zabbix-trigger-timeout?p=245422#post245422

```
{myserver:example.iregexp("/string/",1m)}=1 AND {myserver:example.nodata(1m)}=0
```

some more reading: https://zabbix.org/wiki/Trigger_examples

Comment: The `nodata()` fuction is the right approach. But when used as  `AND {myserver:example.nodata(1m)}=0`, then the trigger will only stop firing, if data is missing. If it should warn you about missing data, you need a condition like `{myserver:example.nodata({$TIMEOUT.MACRO})}=1`. Either in a separate trigger or added as logical `OR` to the existing one.